# Solution to PDE by integrating factor and particular solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

OK, so I'm working on this revision question which looked straight forward, but now it's confusing me.

[image]

I've used the integrating factor method with respect to $x$ and arrived at $u=\frac{5y}{2}+f(y)$

I'm unsure how to proceed at finding a particular solution. I tried solving it like a normal algebra problem, but I have two solutions for $y$. I've integrated with respect to $x$ because of the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ term, but it seems to profit me nothing. Am I approaching this the wrong way? I have nothing to plug the $x$ value into for part b).

Edit: My workings:

IF=$e^{\int 4y  dx}=e^{4yx}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^{4yx}u=10y^2e^{4yx}$

$\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} e^{4yx}u     dx=\int 10y^2e^{4yx} dx$

$e^{4yx}u  = \frac{10y^2e^{4yx} }{4y}+f(y)$

$u  = \frac{10y^2e^{4yx} }{4ye^{4yx}}+f(y)$

$u=\frac{5y}{2}+f(y)$

Comment: Your solution does not solve the differential equation unless $f(y)=0$.

Comment: For my integrating factor, I get $e^{4yx}$ which I multiplied on both sides. Then I integrated and the term seemed to divide straight back out when i tried to solve for $u$. I'm unsure how to do this because my text doesnt have any examples with mixed functions of $x$ and $y$ like this. Can you suggest something I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an algebra mistake in solving for $u$, you forget to divide $f(y)$ by $e^{4yx}$ as well.

Note that 
$$
u_x+4yu=10y^2\implies u_xe^{4yx}+4yue^{4yx}=10y^2e^{4yx}
$$
or rewriting
$$
\partial_x(ue^{4yx})=10y^2e^{4yx}
$$
and integrating both sides in $x$ yields
$$
ue^{4yx}=\frac52ye^{4yx}+f(y)
$$
for some unknown function of $y$, $f(y)$, as you found. So, 
$$
u(x,y)=\frac52 y+e^{-4yx}f(y)
$$
is your general solution.

For the particular, plug in and enforce,
$$
u(1/4,y)=\frac52y+e^{-y}f(y)=5y
\implies f(y)=\frac{5y}{2}e^y
$$

Comment: d'oh! All this beating myself up and it was just that I didn't divide the $f(y)$!! Such as simple error! I knew this problem should not be hard for me, I just couldn't spot my error. Thank you so much!

Comment: @C.Wolfe no problem! Cheers